# XWindows terminal emulation as a .NET Winform component

Tags: .net, winforms, x11

We are writing a kind of industry dashboard that shows many graphical information coming from various sources.

Because one of these sources is a closed Unix application, we would need a XWindow terminal emulator which works as a Winform control.

Has somebody already used such a control, if it exists ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XWindow terminal is pretty complex, I don't think you're going to find one specically targetting embedding in a Windows Forms application, since it is such a niche technology. Fortunately, Windows Forms supports embedding ActiveX controls, which opens up a whole other world of third-party controls. If you could find an embeddable XWindow terminal that is an ActiveX control, then you could possibly use that. I googled and found [WinaXe](http://www.labf.com/winaxe/index.html), which is a windows-based XWindow terminal. From reading their literature, they seem to support embedding as an ActiveX control as well (see http://www.labf.com/winaxe/x11.html and do text search for ActiveX).

Comment: Thank you very much. ActiveX technology went off my mind for unknown reasons. Although it's probably a little bit less obsolete than XWindows, it definitely worth a good search at. WinaXe sounds nice. I remember having used ReflectionX as a Windows based XTerm in the past, I wonder if they provide something too.